Azure AD B2C and External IdP (Micrsoft Account)
I am wanting to allow users to use their Microsoft Account to log into my Single Page Application. The SPA allows users to be created and a Local account in an Azure AD B2C Directory is created with the email address of the user. Is there a way to allow them to use a Microsoft Account or any other provider like Facebook, Google etc. so that on their first log in, it links their Microsoft account to the B2C Local account based on email or some other matching identifier in both and allows them in?
I assume it will have to be through custom policy, but wanting to make sure its technically possible.
I have tried to set this up using User Flows and cant seem to figure out a way to do this, It wants me to create an account in B2C with the Microsoft Account, instead of linking to an existing Local account
EDIT: I have just found this, which I think will do what im after:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/b2acbcfef213413be8747caae98482883a556bca/policies/auto-account-linking

Your edit is correct - that is the sample you would need to follow and it is only available via custom policies.
